# iframing in header that has CSS dropdowns in it - good solution to get the dropdowns outside of the iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm working on migrating a fairly large site to a new framework, but we're doing it in separate stages, so I'm trying to find a good way to wrap the current layout around my new framework.  Ideally, a simple structure like this would suffice:

```
<body>
   <iframe src="old_framework/top.php" />
   <div id="main_content"></div>
   <iframe src="old_framework/bottom.php" />
</body>
```

Problem being that top.php is a menu with CSS dropdowns and they need to overlap #main_content.

I get that I can't break out of top.php's iframe like that, so this structure will not work, but I'm curious if anyone has encountered a similar situation and found a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, why are you making an iframe-based layout??? It's IMO the worst way to do it...

Comment: An iFrame is basically a mini-browser. You can't exceed the browser's borders, and anything that is larger than the browser's dimensions will cause a scroll bar. Congratulations on your impending "Worst Layout Implementation of 2011" award though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the comments from everyone.  I wound up just totally re-implementing the old layout in my new framework.  Took a little bit, but definitely less hacky than any other solution.

@Joel Etherton: I actually audibly LOL'd when I read your comment.  Rest assured, I won't be receiving said award now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with the iframes cannot be fixed!

Another way to solve the problem could be removing iframes and, for example, try to do this way:

```
<body>
   <div id="top"><?php include_once("old_framework/top.php"); ?></div>
   <div id="main_content"></div>
   <div id="bottom"><?php include_once("old_framework/bottom.php"); ?></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ya I'd considered this.  The old framework needs to set itself up every page load (hence the iframe idea), so I don't think I could actually rip out the top and bottom includes like that without simulating a lot of that setup in the new app.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, using php (or similar) includes will save you a lot of headaches.  Iframes aren't used much any more and are nothing but trouble in my experience.

Comment: I agree about iframes in general, but they've actually been invaluable for a number of elements in our app.  For instance, we work with a number of different vendors and sometimes we want to pull in pieces of their app, or they want to pull in pieces of ours to show in their app.  Not perfect, but it does make sure the interface is the same throughout the different areas.